# Normalization Form

Tags: database-normalization, 3nf, bcnf

would like to ask a question that related with normalization form.

```html
R = A,B,C,D
AB -> CD
CD -> AB
```

Is this is 3NF with BCNF ? why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two dependencies are a cover of all the dependencies holding on the relation, it is in BCNF and in 3NF, since the candidate keys are AB and CD.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But it is violates BCNF because right hand side cannot use candidate key as its values?

Comment: No problem for this. The important thing is the left hand side that must be a super key.